# How to launch a Uikit notification from AngularJS controller

Tags: angularjs

I want launch a uikit notification after login in my system or when I fail in the login by password or user incorrect. I think that I can to do it using AngularJS. In my project when I try login, first my data are send to a controller that send this data a django view.

login.html

```
  <div class="input" ng-controller="conIngreso">

    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="login-input-group spacer-field">
      <span class="login-input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-at fa-fw"></i>
      </span>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" ng-model="email">
    </div>
    <div class="login-input-group">
      <span class="login-input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i>
      </span>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" ng-model="password">
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg submit" type="submit" ng-click="ingresar(email, password)">Ingresar</button>
  </div>
```

conIngreso.js

```
var app = angular.module('appLogin');

app.controller('conIngreso', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
$scope.user={email:'',password:''}

$scope.ingresar=function(email,password){
    $http({method:'POST',
        url:'/cliente/ingreso/',
        data:$.param({email: email, password: password})
    }).then(
        function(response2){
            //UIkit.notification("...", {pos: 'top-right'});
            window.location.href='javascript:history.back()';
        },function(response2){
            $scope.user = response2.data || 'Request failed';
        }
    );
}
}])
```

In the conIngreso.js file above I try to do it before window.location...

But does not work

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its

```
UIkit.notify
```

and you are using

```
UIkit.notification
```

Comment: I'm using this                                                                     
    UIkit.notification({
        message: "<span uk-icon='icon: check'></span> Welcome",
        status: 'success',
        pos: 'top-center',
        timeout: 5000
    });